# Multiple imputation when explained variance of imputation model is low

Tags: r-squared, multiple-imputation

I am thinking about using multiple imputation to impute missing values on the dependent variable (continuous) in my analysis. In the imputation model, I considered variables that are associated with my dependent variable and variables that are related to the missing mechanism.

It turned out that the R-squared of a linear regression model including all variables that I want to use for the imputation model is only 20%.

Is it reasonable to impute values on the dependent variable although the R-squared of the imputation model is fairly low?

Comment: Why do you think that $R^2$ can be used to decide whether imputation model is reasonable or not? Do you read it somewhere? Can you share with us the source?

Comment: Thanks @T.E.G for your comment. I was just wondering whether a prediction should based on a poor fitted model. "A critical point in our application is the poor prediction of blood pressure (multiple r2 (SBP) 0.24 and r2 (DBP) 0.17). The generated imputations thus are quite uncertain and contain considerable residual noise." Look at the conclusion in the paper by [VAN BUUREN, BOSHUIZEN AND KNOOK 1999](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/publications/Multiple%20imputation%20-%20Stat%20Med%201999.pdf)

Comment: OK, but the comment from van Buren is (at least in what you quoted) not necessarily arguing against imputation.  It's just saying that imputation was hard.

Comment: @Peter Flom. Thanks for commenting! Well, but do we not want to have a "certain" imputation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "certain" imputation. The reason for MI rather than (say) mean substitution is that it captures the variation in the data set.  Sure, it makes the subsequent analysis "easier" if there is less variation, but those are your data.  They are, apparently, messy.